# Smart Contract Deployment to MainNet Pending Status

Tags: ethereum, truffle, pending-transition

I have my own Ehereum cient node running OpenEthereum 3.0.1. I am using Truffle Suite to deploy my smart contract to MainNet, using my node as RPC_URL. The Truffle migration command issued the following:

## 1_initial_migration.js

Deploying 'Migrations'

---

> block number:        10288818
>   block timestamp:     1592471208
>   account:             0xmyaccountnumber
>   balance:             0.1797474439
>   gas used:            210237 (0x3353d)
>   gas price:           2 gwei
>   value sent:          0 ETH
>   total cost:          0.000420474 ETH

---

> Total cost:         0.000420474 ETH

## 2_deploy_contracts.js

Deploying 'AuthentoFile'

---

> block number:        10288820
>   block timestamp:     1592471211
>   account:             0xmyAcountNumber
>   balance:             0.1769681859
>   gas used:            1362266 (0x14c95a)
>   gas price:           2 gwei
>   value sent:          0 ETH
>   total cost:          0.002724532 ETH

---

> Total cost:         0.002724532 ETH

## Summary

> Total deployments:   2
>   Final cost:          0.003145006 ETH

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'mainnet'
>   Network id:      1
>   Block gas limit: 9990236 (0x98705c)

## 1_initial_migration.js

Deploying 'Migrations'

---

> transaction hash:    0x77eac6bee9baeb315e7e52d31d13a9ab4241676c2ec2b4a5e7cf2071281ffe1a

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!.

```
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
```

This was the second time I tried to deploy. I have 2 transactions for the Contract Deployment that are still pending on EtherScan.io. The tx hashes are

0x77eac6bee9baeb315e7e52d31d13a9ab4241676c2ec2b4a5e7cf2071281ffe1a  and
0xc0a28527f1fcebc0bdf9ae18479831eaf026b350420a3134bcd14b44f520b812

My Open Ethereum node is also showing these as pending transactions.

Will these transactions ever get mined? If not, is there anyway to "cancel" these pending transactions?

Any insight or help would be much appreciated!